# stick-slip oscillator: Missed WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

Using Mathematica I try to modell the stick slip effect as recommended in the documentation (WhenEvent).

The initial condition starts from a state `x[0]==0,x'[0]==0,F[0]==0` with fullfilled stick- condtions.

Here the modell which seems to work

```
Clear[X, HAFT, frast]
F[t_]:= Sin[2 Pi 5 t];
frast = .5;
Manipulate[
{X, HAFT} = NDSolveValue[{.1 x''[t] == (1 - haft[t])  F[t] ,
x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, haft[0] == 1
, 
Apply[WhenEvent, { x'[t] == 0 ,haft[t] -> Boole[-frast < F[t] < frast]}]
, Apply[WhenEvent, {Abs[ F[t] ] > frast, haft[t] -> 0}]
} 
, {x, haft}, {t, 0, tsim}, DiscreteVariables -> haft ];
Plot[{X[t], X'[t], F[t], HAFT[t]}, {t, 0, tsim}, PlotRange -> All,GridLines-> {None, {-frast, frast}}, MaxRecursion -> 10 ,PlotLegends -> {"pos","velocity", "force" , "stick==True"}]
, {{tsim, 1}, 0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

problems occur if I change the simulation time tsim to 1.5(example):

[image]

I'm wondering why MMA seems to miss the first event (`t~=0.015,force==0.5`)?

My question:
Is it possible to make the eventdetection more robust.

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the definition of `F`?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question!

Comment: Funny, in _v9.0.1_ and _v11.2_ the result looks fine for `tsim=1.5`, but misses every event for `tsim=1`. I find 2 workarounds in these two versions: 1. `MaxStepSize -> 0.01`, 2. `"DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"`. Do these solutions work on your version, too?

Comment: My version is 11.0.1 : Using `MaxStepSize-> ` is perhaps a workaround...